# Fix warp in recaster (lua)

Tags: lua, rendering, raycasting, love2d

```
function RENDER_RAY(plr,rayNumber,Ray_Distance,RayAmount,rayAngle)
    local theta = plr.angle - FOV/2
    local diss = Ray_Distance * math.cos(math.rad(theta - plr.angle))

    local screenWidth = love.graphics.getWidth()
    local screenHeight = love.graphics.getHeight()
    local colorDistance = (255 - diss/1.5)/255
    if colorDistance > 0 then
        love.graphics.setColor(colorDistance,colorDistance,colorDistance,1)
    else
        love.graphics.setColor(0,0,0,1)
    end
    local wallHeight = math.Clamp(screenHeight-diss, 0 , 99999999)
    love.graphics.rectangle("fill",(screenWidth/RayAmount) * rayNumber,(screenHeight/2)- 
    allHeight/2,screenWidth/RayAmount,wallHeight)
end
```

(using love2d)

this is the function that renders the Columbs.
its called every time a new ray is casted, so the function is only dealing with 1 ray at a time.

plr is just the plr object that contains the (x,y,angle) of the player
everything like plr.angle and RayAngle is just the standard math.rad
and ray_distance is just the distance from the ray HIT x y and the player x y

as you can see iv tried fixing the warping but its not going away
Iv tried to find a good solution but the best one i could find has no effect on the warping!

Screenshots:

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Comment: It's not clear what is your problem (and what "warping" is).  Can you post a picture rendered by your code to make the problem more obvious?

Comment: sorry i didn't think to add screen shots, added now.

Comment: Nice screenshots!  But I still don't see the problem.  What is not good enough on the rendered images?

Comment: It seems like you reduce the wall height linearly, but in reality it's a division. E.g. `wallHeight = screenHeight / diss`. At distances larger than screenHeight, your wall would become inverted (if you wouldn't have clamped it).